# How to hide zero values in a pie chart with the EPPLUS library

Tags: c#, pie-chart, epplus

I'm developing with c# and use the EPPLUS library to create excel sheets, specifically 
I've created pie charts where I also show zero values but I would like to remove them. I have not been able to find any workaround. below the code I use:

```
<pre>    int chart_RegionHeaderRow = 1;
int chart_RegionHeaderColumn = 13;
firstRowCategory = 2;
lastRowCategory = 2;
firstColCategory = 3;
lastColCategory = firstColCategory + pDeployVersionSet.Length - 1;

int firstColValue = 3;
int lastColValue = firstColValue + pDeployVersionSet.Length - 1;
int firstRowSerie = 3;

int rowCR = chart_RegionHeaderRow;
int colCR = chart_RegionHeaderColumn;

int chart_RegionColStep = 6;
int chart_RegionRowStep = 16;

//Create the Region chart WW
var chartWW = (ExcelPieChart)worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("pieChartDeployWW", eChartType.Pie);
chartWW.SetSize(300, 300);
chartWW.SetPosition(rowCR, 0, colCR, 0);
chartWW.Title.Text = "WW";

chartWW.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
chartWW.DataLabel.ShowPercent = true;
chartWW.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
indexSerie = firstRowSerie;
chartWW.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(indexSerie + _RegionsSet.Length, 
     firstColValue, 
     indexSerie + _RegionsSet.Length,
     lastColValue),
       ExcelRange.GetAddress(firstRowCategory, firstColCategory, lastRowCategory, lastColCategory <code>
```

and also the resulting excel file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX5I8.png)

I hope somebody can give me directions. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Could you share some code?  Take a look at this link for guidance on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

My chart data is imported from .csv files which imports blanks as text.
This helped me get rid of Zero values on my charts.

```
sheet.Cells["B33"].Clear();
```

My charts are line charts but it may work for you as well.

Comment: it does not work, try checking the code and the result I posted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply took the size to 0.
Not very elegant but it works.

```
var deletePieChart = ws.Drawings["Chart 6"] as ExcelPieChart;
deletePieChart.SetSize(0, 0);
```